# How to increase TCP window size

Tags: tcp

I am working on a video streaming server which streams video at 6Mbps rate. When checked through Wireshark, I noticed that the window size does not go above 3100 or so. For testing purpose, I connected an IP Camera and checked window size. For this, I found that the window size is approximately 6100.

I increased the send buffer size of my application's TCP socket. But, no luck. It actually reduced the window size to 1560 or so. Any suggestion on how to increase the window size.

My application's target recipient is a device on LAN.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. TCP has no concept of "window" or "window size" at all. Actually there aren't many concepts over TCP at all - its just a stream of bytes. Are you referring to a particular (video streaming) protocol over TCP? If so then which one?

Comment: Yes, I am using RTSP video streaming protocol.

Comment: What window are you referring to? TCP has congestion window and flow control window.

Answer (score 1):

> I increased the **send** buffer size of my application's TCP socket. But, no luck. It actually reduced the window size to 1560 or so.

The **receive** window size is controlled by the **receive** socket buffer size on the reciever.

Comment: RTSP receiver that we are using for both IP Camera and our application is using the same type of socket. Wondering how does the receive window size differ when recipient code is same for both. Does MTU size 
 of sender socket change the window size?

Comment: @VenkataSubbarao Sent data reduces the receiver window size, until the data is consumed by the receiver application.

Comment: Which socket option I should try to reduce packet drops. I tried setting socket option TCP_NODELAY to 1. But, no luck.

Comment: @VenkataSubbarao It sounds like you try applying random socket options. Get "Unix Network Programming" book and read it.

Comment: Thanks. I am studying. B/w, I am using live555 RTSP server for streaming.